# Differences between using ? and :param in prepare statement

Tags: php, database, pdo, prepared-statement, named-parameters

Let's say I want to select records where `Id = 30`. Prepared statements allow two ways of binding parameters:

> question marks

```
$id = 30;
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pdo_db WHERE id > ?");
$q->execute(array($id));  // Here above ID will be passed
```

> named parameters

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `pdo_db` WHERE `id` > :id");
$sth->execute(array(
  ':id' => 30
));
```

Both are working fine and give accurate results but I am not able to get the exact differences between these two nor when I should use one or another?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Question mark parameters are called **positional** parameters.

Parameters defined with `:` and a name are called **named** parameters.

The rule is that you can't mix the two in your prepared statement.

Positional parameters work in a simple way - if you have two positional parameters, you can specify an array with two elements. Array values will be bound in order as they appear in the array.

Named parameters are a bit trickier, they *don't have to be bound in order they appear*. You can also repeat one named parameter multiple times in the statement, but you can bind it only once to pass the value - that last part works when PDO is set to emulation via `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);`.

Answer (score 4):

This seesm to be more of a preference based question as there isn't a strict right or wrong answer.

Personally I avoid `?` as it's tightly tied to the order of parameters. Although theoretically you shouldn't be able to mess this up by adding or removing binding a single binding, it just seems like it's asking for trouble. It is (slightly) less work though.

`:name` is more concise and is tightly bound to the identification of bindings, not arbitrarily to the order. It involves a (tiny) bit more work but it is much easier to debug, and less prone to mistakes.

I prefer being (slightly) concise over writing (slightly) less code.

Answer (score 2):

***These are different placeholders***

```
   ? -- > question mark placeholders
   :name --> named Placeholders
```

The difference between `named and question mark placeholders` is that with question mark placeholders *you'll have to take care about the order in which they will be bound to the query*.